# If I was to open a US based XMR exchange what laws I need to consider?

Tags: exchange, legal

Are there any laws restricting me from opening a Massachusetts, USA based Monero which would allow exchanges from fiat to XMR?

Comment: "laws, security issues, etc." is too broad and "how much money should be invested before attempting?" is too speculative.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an entire business plan (which would be the size of an encyclopedia). I would try to limit one category per question.

Comment: I attempted to edit it.

Comment: What State would it be?

Comment: @PyRulez Massachusess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least you would have to register as a [money services business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_services_business), which Poloniex and I believe Bittrex both have, and then as a MSB you would have to perform KYC/AML and record keeping to comply with the [Bank Secrecy Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Secrecy_Act) to detect and prevent money laundering. IANAL.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult and very expensive in the US. And even if you pay and jump through all the hoops, nothing is certain. This is how banks keep the competition out. I would suggest looking into more friendly countries abroad, or consider decentralized solutions.